# Include time in 3 minute intervals in Cell value assignment

Tags: excel, vba

So I've got two work sheets one is "datafeed" and other is "Record". In my datafeed sheet there is live data constantly being updated and in the record sheet it is stored every 3 miniutes everything works perfectly fine but now all I want is to add a time for every 3 min for eg if at 9:00 the data is 100 then I want that time as well as my data both over there like this 9:00 100, 9:03 140, 9:06 256, etc. Here is my code just want to show the time as well and if you want to know where I want the time the cell is (A2):

Vba Code:

```
Sub update()

With Sheets("record")
    rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Range(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, 2)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("B66").Value
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 4), .Cells(rw, 4)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("V66").Value

    .Range(.Cells(rw, 5), .Cells(rw, 5)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("B67").Value
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 7), .Cells(rw, 7)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("V67").Value

    .Range(.Cells(rw, 8), .Cells(rw, 8)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("B68").Value
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 10), .Cells(rw, 10)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("V68").Value

    .Range(.Cells(rw, 11), .Cells(rw, 11)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("B69").Value
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 13), .Cells(rw, 13)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("V69").Value

    .Range(.Cells(rw, 14), .Cells(rw, 14)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("B70").Value
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 16), .Cells(rw, 16)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("V70").Value

    .Range(.Cells(rw, 17), .Cells(rw, 17)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("B71").Value
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 19), .Cells(rw, 19)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("V71").Value

    .Range(.Cells(rw, 20), .Cells(rw, 20)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("B72").Value
    .Range(.Cells(rw, 22), .Cells(rw, 22)).Value = Sheets("datafeed").Range("V72").Value
End With
Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 3, 0), "update"   ' run again after 5 minutes
End Sub
```

Comment: I've added an answer that will include the *current system time* at the time the code is run... I then thought perhaps the time values are already documented in another column for example - If my answer doesn't provide a solution, consider editing your question to include more clarity towards what you are trying to do, some data samples and expected outcome samples also - the cleared your question, the easier it is to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`Time()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function will return the system time in `"hh:mm:ss AM/PM"` format, using the [`Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function we can manipulate the output format of the `Time()` function:

### For the "hh:mm:ss AM/PM" format

```
Range(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, 2)).Value = Time() & " " & Sheets("datafeed").Range("B66").Value
```

### For the "hh:mm" format (which is in 24hr time)

```
Range(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, 2)).Value = Format(time(), "hh:mm"))  & " " & Sheets("datafeed").Range("B66").Value
```

### For "hh:mm AM/PM" format:

```
Range(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, 2)).Value = Format(time(), "hh:mm AM/PM"))  & " " & Sheets("datafeed").Range("B66").Value
```

### And if you just need "hh:mm" in the 12 hour format, try:

```
Range(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, 2)).Value = Mid(Format(Time(), "hh:mm AM/PM"),1,5) & " " &  Sheets("datafeed").Range("B66").Value
```

If the code may take some time to execute (longer than one minute) you may consider assigning the time value to a variable at the start of the code and use the variable instead:

```
Dim myTimeValue As String

myTimeValue = Mid(Format(Time(), "hh:mm AM/PM"), 1, 5)

With Sheets("record")
    rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, 2)).Value = myTimeValue  & " " & Sheets("datafeed").Range("B66").Value
    ...
    'The rest of your code here
End With
...
'The rest of your code here
```

Comment: Thank you so much that really worked, really appreciate it. That's it I just wanted the time to display before my data cells and your given answer is doing the same. So thanks once again.